# IE throws Security Error when calling toDataUrl on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas, svg

first of all, I know that accessing `toDataURL` method of canvas when its source image is from  another origin is a security issue.

but in my case, I am using `data:` url as the source of my `img` and then use `img` and draw it on `canvas` and then call `canvas.toDataUrl`.

this works fine on Chrome and Firefox but fails with security error in IE!

any idea?

```
...
var svgxml = getxmlsvg();
img.onload = function(){
    canvas.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // <--- security error
}
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([svgxml], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" }))
```

Here is the quote from [svgopen.org](http://svgopen.org/2010/papers/62-From_SVG_to_Canvas_and_Back/#security_issues)

> Transferring data from SVG to Canvas has security issues, which cause
>   Canvas to become write-only. We argue that these issues could be
>   avoided with our SVG.toDataURL() proposal (section "Recommendations").
>
> Same Origin and Canvas Origin Policy
>
> Web pages are composed of different elements coming from different
>   origins. Elements coming from the same origin are considered to be
>   safe [Origin10].
>
> Canvas has powerful image reading and writing capabilities. It would
>   be trivial to use canvas as middleman for transfering a local image to
>   a third-party just by loading image into Canvas element from file://
>   -URL and then sending the pixel data from the Canvas element to any host with JavaScript.
>
> To prevent information leakage with Canvas, browsers are carefully
>   protecting the usage of Canvas when the source for image data is not
>   safe. All Canvas elements are created as their origin-clean attribute
>   set to true. When any of the actions that may potentially be used for
>   using Canvas element to transfer content that violates the same origin
>   policy, the origin-clean property is permanently set to false.
>
> If methods that return the pixel data stored in canvas, such as
>   toDataURL() or getImageData(), are called on the Canvas element whose
>   origin-clean is false, then a DOMException 18 SECURITY_ERR is raised
>   [Canvas10].

But I am creating SVG on the fly in the browser.

Comment: Sounds to me like a bug in IE... What version of IE is this?

Comment: I think so, I am using IE 11. I don't remember correctly but it seems that it's because drawing svg image on canvas makes it `write-only`! and prevents further read operations!!

I've updated the question.

Comment: IE has funky levels of privacy/security, not necessarily in line with other browsers. Try lowering them down to minimum before pursuing whether or not it's a bug in IE

Comment: @Bakhshi: Have you read that whole document which you found? It seems to contain the answer you are looking for: "*SVG can potentially contain content from multiple origins and browsers tend to blacklist any content with the MIME type image/svg+xml as multi-origin content without even testing the actual content. […]*" While [Webkit has been fixed](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29305) in the while, IE still seems to show this behaviour

Comment: yeah you're right @Bergi . it seems that the only option to render my svg as png would be `canvg` which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Did you find a solution other that canvg?

Comment: @user3428801 unfortunately no!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I changed the graphic elements that make up the image from svg to png.  When using svg, I am seeing a security error in IE 11 (and 10), not Chrome, when I use toDataURL. Building the graphic using png elements, it's fine.

There is a 2nd problem with svgs not resizing properly in IE 11, so that's another strike against using svgs with IE.

Comment: Is there a solution to this? Facing same issue getting data uri png from svg .

Answer (score 1):

There exists a library that abstracts the svg --> canvas --> png and adds a method to the SVG element so that in any browser you can just call mySvg.toDataUrl() with a callback and the option "canvg":

https://github.com/sampumon/SVG.toDataURL

This implementation takes into account security exceptions so you can get past the permissions error you are encountering.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.github.io/canvg/rgbcolor.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.github.io/canvg/StackBlur.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js"></script> 
<script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rawgit.com/sampumon/SVG.toDataURL/master/svg_todataurl.js"></script>

mySVGelement.toDataURL("image/png", {
  renderer: "canvg"
  callback: function(data) {
      image.src = data;
  }
});
</script>
```

**Compatibility**:

```
Browser     E x p o r t i n g  f o r m a t
            SVG+XML  PNG/canvg  PNG/native
IE           9+       9+         -
Chrome       +        +          33+ ²
Safari       +        +          -
Firefox      +        +          11+ ¹
Opera        +        +          -
```

Comment: doesn't work with ie11. I tried here: http://sampumon.github.io/SVG.toDataURL/butterfly_test.html