# Save inline SVG as JPEG/PNG/SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, png, jpeg

I have an inline SVG in my html, and I need to be able to save this as either a JPEG, PNG or SVG.

I have tried a few different methods with converting the SVG to canvas and then converting to JPEG, but I haven't been able to get these working.

Here is an example of my inline SVG.

```css
.font {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.name {
 font-size: 64pt;
}
.top-bar-text {
 font-size: 32pt;
}
.font tspan {
 dominant-baseline: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<svg width="256" height="256" id="icon">
  <rect class="bg1" id="bg_color_1" x="0" y="0" width="256" height="256" fill="#4cbc5a" />
  <path class="bg2" id="bg_color_2" d="M 0 96 L0,256 L256,256 L256,96 s -128 96 -256 0" fill="#08a21c" />
  <text id="left_corner_text" x="24" y="36" width="48" height="64" class="top_bar lct font top-bar-text" text-anchor="middle" fill="#ffffff"><tspan>1</tspan></text>
  <text id="right_corner_text" x="232" y="36" width="48" height="64" class="top_bar rct font top-bar-text" text-anchor="middle" fill="#ffffff"><tspan>2</tspan></text>
  <text id="line_1_text" transform="scale(1,2)" x="128" y="90" width="256" height="192" class="l1t font name" text-anchor="middle" fill="#ffffff"><tspan>ABC</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

Also, not all the elements need to be exported, as some of the options the user has is to remove the top corner numbers.

I would like for when it's been converted to download straight to the browser.

Answer (score 91):

Nowadays this is pretty simple.

The basic idea is:

1. SVG to canvas
2. canvas to dataUrl
3. trigger download from dataUrl

---

*it actually works outside of the Stack Overflow snippet*

```js
function triggerDownload(imgURI) {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = 'MY_COOL_IMAGE.png'; // filename
  a.target = '_blank';
  a.href = imgURI;

  // trigger download button
  // (set `bubbles` to false here.
  // or just `a.click()` if you don't care about bubbling)
  a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: false,
    cancelable: true
  }));
}

const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const svgNode = document.querySelector('svg');
  const svgString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svgNode);
  const svgBlob = new Blob([svgString], {
    type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
  });

  const DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
  const url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

  const image = new Image();
  image.width = svgNode.width.baseVal.value;
  image.height = svgNode.height.baseVal.value;
  image.src = url;
  image.onload = function () {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

    const imgURI = canvas
      .toDataURL('image/png')
      .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');
    triggerDownload(imgURI);
  };
});
```

```html
<button>svg to png</button>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="200" height="200">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" />
  <text x="0" y="100">Look, i'm cool</text>
</svg>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Regarding the downloading part, you can set up a filename, image width and height and etc etc (although mostly not included in this example). Some days ago I answered a question on how to download a specific portion of HTML from the given page. It might be useful regarding the downloading part: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28087280/2178180

**update 2021-11-30**: now letting you specify the filename 
**update 2023-06-29**: improve code readability and ensure image width and height match the SVG.

Comment: How does this work?  I copy the exact code and i cannot replicate it. Can you put it in jsfiddle?

Comment: Figured it out. The <script></script> portion needs to come after the <canvas> and all of the code. Before closing body tag.

Comment: Sorry for another response - is there any reason why this does  not work in IE or FireFox?

Comment: Hi! Support in IE is hard baceuse it does not support the [Blob api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) - [see caniuse blob](http://caniuse.com/#search=Blob). I also think that the MouseEvent interface is not properly set (just guessing). Anyway, it should work well in Firefox. In which version have you tried? Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LznLjxq7/ .

Comment: Thanks. The jsfiddle version you provided works in firefox. I.E. loses again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The jsfiddle version does not seem to work for me in Chrome or Safari. Firefox is fine, but it's not really a solution if it only works in one browser.  What is the reason for this, and can anyone offer any insights as to why, or what might be done, to remedy the situation?  thanks.

Comment: This is kind of interesting… the reason I was searching for this and why i thought it was reasonable to expect a browser to have built in options for saving/printing/exporting inline SVG documents is because existing native options already exist for the canvas element. So while it makes perfect sense that converting the SVG to canvas would work as a way to get those options, my real question is : "shouldn't similar options already be built in to the browser for embedded SVGs?" Is there a reason to not expect similar functionality between the two in this context?

Comment: I have a `<image>` tag inside the svg, but only the lines/paths get downloaded, do you have any clue?

Comment: How can you make this a pdf?

Comment: @CiroCosta This is not working in iPhone any idea why? `img.onload` method is not trigger in iPhone.

Comment: your sample is not working in IE and edge browser.. how to achieve this? @CiroCosta

Comment: I have the same Problem as Patrick. Images are not rendered and also texts have the wrong font. Any solution found?

Comment: How to change sizes when converting it to PNG. Need to accommodate the size changes for my website. Please do help me.

Comment: This is a great answer, but in order to have the end image have the same sizing as the svg, make your canvas have the html(not css) attributes height and width. Its probably a good idea to do this onClick and make it grab the dimensions of the svg.

Comment: Returns blank image on Firefox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690643/firefox-error-rendering-an-svg-image-to-html5-canvas-with-drawimage Bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700533

Comment: ... if svg tag attributes width and height are not defined. So the snippet works fine.

Comment: Safari doesn't seem to like the `;charset=utf-8` bit on the Blob type. This causes the `img.onload` not called problems. For sizing, I size my `canvas` and then also provide `width` and `height` params to the `drawImage(...)` call.

Comment: This is excellent, I tried adding my own svg element which showed on screen in js.fiddle but when I click the button, only some of the svg ended up in a png and in really bad resolution and quality. Are there any updates to this excellent post? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Here's a solution that works in IE11 as well.**

I just did a bunch of testing of various methods of this and while the above answer by Ciro Costa is fantastic in that it works in Firefox and Chrome it does not work in IE11. IE11 [fails due to a security issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322745/ie-throws-security-error-when-calling-todataurl-on-canvas) with rendering an svg to the canvas which requires a canvas implementation, [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg). Here's a solution using `canvg` that's pretty terse and works in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE11.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/StefanValentin/9mudw0ts/

**DOM**

```
<svg
  id="my-svg"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  version="1.1"
  width="200"
  height="200"
>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" />
  <text x="0" y="100">Look, i'm cool</text>
</svg>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var svg = document.querySelector('#my-svg');
var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
// We can just create a canvas element inline so you don't even need one on the DOM. Cool!
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvg(canvas, data, {
  renderCallback: function() {
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        download('MyImageName.png', blob);
    });
  }
});
```

The `download` function above could be whatever you want to do, as there are many ways to trigger a download via JavaScript. Here's the one we use that works in all the browsers I've tested.

```
// Initiate download of blob
function download(
  filename, // string
  blob // Blob
) {
  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
    const elem = window.document.createElement('a');
    elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    elem.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
    elem.click();
    document.body.removeChild(elem);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is canvg() defined?

Comment: In the JSFiddle if you check the resources you'll see canvg.min imported. That exposes `canvg` as a global. If you look at the docs though you can import it via npm and reference it by importing it: https://github.com/canvg/canvg

Answer (score 4):

**The solution for saving inline SVG as SVG file**

Works in modern browsers

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect fill="red" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
</svg>

<button>Save to SVG</button>
```

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button')
let svg = document.querySelector('svg')

let triggerDownload = (imgURI, fileName) => {
    let a = document.createElement('a')

    a.setAttribute('download', 'image.svg')
    a.setAttribute('href', imgURI)
    a.setAttribute('target', '_blank')

    a.click()
}

let save = () => {
    let data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg)
    let svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'})
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob)

    triggerDownload(url)
}

let btn = document.querySelector('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', save)
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/udovichenko/pen/yLXaWLB

Answer (score 1):

Working off @CiroCosta. 1 option if you are having trouble exporting an  element you could just draw the image to the canvas before drawing the svg image

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

  // get the raw image from the DOM
  var rawImage = document.getElementById('yourimageID');
  var img = new Image();
  var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

  img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(rawImage, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

    var imgURI = canvas
      .toDataURL('image/png')
      .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');

    triggerDownload(imgURI);
  };

  img.src = url;
});
```

Worked for me but only for png and jpeg. SVG files still only display inline elements and not  tags

EDIT: The way you create an svg like this is actually by converting the image tag into Base64 and the setting that as the xlink:href in the image attributes like this:

```
<image id="crop" width="725" height="1764" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo ... " />
```

and then triggering the download on the whole svg url like this:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

  var rawImage = document.getElementById('yourimageID');
  var img = new Image();
  var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

  img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    triggerDownload(url);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
};
```

you can convert pngs like this [here](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-image-data-uri-javascript):

```
function getDataUri(url, callback) {
  var image = new Image();

  image.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);

    // Get raw image data
    callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ''));

    // ... or get as Data URI
    callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
  };

  image.src = url;
}
```

then setting the attribute

```
getDataUri('localImagepath', function (dataUri) {
  image.setAttribute('xlink:href', dataUri);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @ciro costa does help, but the generated png height is not working correctly unless the canvas height and width is set.

```js
function downloadImg() {
  const svgElem = document.querySelector('svg')
  const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
  let svgData = serializer.serializeToString(svgElem);
  svgData = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>\r\n' + svgData;
  const svgBlob = new Blob([svgData], {
    type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8',
  });
  let DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
  const url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const domRect = svgElem.getBBox();
    canvas.width = domRect.width;
    canvas.height = domRect.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, domRect.width, domRect.height);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

    const imgURI = canvas
      .toDataURL('image/png')
      .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');

    download(imgURI);
  };
  img.onerror = (e) => {
    console.error('Image not loaded', e);
  };

  img.src = url;
}

function download(href) {
  let download = document.createElement('a');
  download.href = href;
  download.download = 'img.png';
  download.click();
  download.remove();
}
```

```html
<svg width="256" height="256" id="icon">
      <rect class="bg1" id="bg_color_1" x="0" y="0" width="256" height="256" fill="#4cbc5a" />
    </svg>

<div>
  <button onclick="downloadImg()">Download</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, the solutions presented here work, but don't forget to explicitly set the canvas size in pixels, otherwise the image may be cropped.
For example:

```js
// get the size of the svg image
const { width, height } = svg.getBBox();

// create a canvas and set its size
var canvas = document.createElement(`canvas`);
canvas.setAttribute(`width`, width);
canvas.setAttribute(`height`, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to example, but JavaScript section is simplify to you.

```js
function SVGPNG(svg, cb) {
  let temp = document.createElement("img");
  let imageSrc = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([svg], { type: "image/svg+xml" })
  );

  temp.src = imageSrc;
  temp.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed;left:-200vw;");
  document.body.appendChild(temp);
  temp.onload = function onload() {
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = temp.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = temp.clientHeight;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(temp, 0, 0);
    let src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    cb(src, canvas);
    temp.remove();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(imageSrc);
  };
}

function onPaste(e) {
  SVGPNG(e.target.value, (src) => {
    document.getElementById("output").value = src;
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

textarea {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  resize: none;
  outlined: solid 1px #999;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="60" rows="20" autofocus onchange="onPaste">Paste your SVG code here...</textarea>
<textarea cols="60" rows="20" readonly id="output">Your output here...</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

Keeping it simple, place an svg, a canvas and an empty img into the HTML. Set all to the same size. The javascript will use the svg to create a binary large object which is then rendered in the canvas as a png image. The function call creates a clone of the canvas and converts it into a jpeg.

```js
function fjpg(){
 clone = c.cloneNode(true);
 ctx = clone.getContext('2d');
 ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, clone.width, clone.height);
 ctx.drawImage(c, 0, 0);
 document.all.jp1.src=clone.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
 ctx = c.getContext('2d');
 svgBlob = new Blob( [dataPNG], { type: 'image/svg+xml' } );
 urlPNG = self.URL.createObjectURL( svgBlob );
 img = new Image();
 img.onload = function () {ctx.drawImage(img,0,0)}
 img.src = urlPNG;
}
c = document.all.canvas0;
ctx = c.getContext('2d');
data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(document.all.svg0);
dataJPG = data.replace('>SVG<','>JPG<');
dataPNG = data.replace('>SVG<','>PNG<');
svgBlob = new Blob( [dataJPG], { type: 'image/svg+xml' } );
urlJPG = self.URL.createObjectURL( svgBlob );
img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
 ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
 fjpg();
}
img.src = urlJPG;
```

```html
<svg id='svg0' height=180 width=180><rect width=100% height=100% fill=red /><circle cx=90 cy=90 r=80 fill=green /><text x=90 y=105 font-size=60 text-anchor=middle fill=yellow>SVG</text></svg>
<canvas id="canvas0" height=180 width=180></canvas>
<img src='' id='jp1'>
```