# Using <canvas> drawImage inside an onload isn't drawing anything in Firefox

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to get a generates SVG to draw inside a canvas. The code below works OK in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 100px; height; 100px">
      <rect x="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" fill="pink" />
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25"/>
    </svg>
    <canvas style="border: 1px dashed black; height: 100px; width: 100px">
    </canvas>

    <script>
      const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
      const svg = document.querySelector("svg")

      const outerHTML = svg.cloneNode(true).outerHTML
      const blob = new Blob([outerHTML],{type:'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
      let url = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
      let blobURL = url.createObjectURL(blob);

      const img = document.createElement("img")
      document.querySelector("body").appendChild(img)

      img.onload = () => {
        try {
          canvas.height = 100
          canvas.width = 100
          let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
          ctx.clearRect(10,20,30,40);
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e)
        }
      };
      img.src = blobURL
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Everything appears to work here -- including the image loading -- except for the `drawImage` call. The small pink rounded-rect with the black circle is the SVG. The big one on the bottom is the same thing loaded into an `img` element. (The "0.5ms" is because this is being loaded via a Rails app but that's inconsequential)

[image: screenshot]

The dashed box is the canvas that I'm trying to draw into. The `fillRect` and `clearRect` work. I'm inside the onload, so I know the image has finished loading. The dimensions are all correct. The image is loaded into the `img` element, so I know the browser can handle the blob.

I don't know what else could be wrong here.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great clue. Now I know it works in Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: Good call--I was able to reproduce so I'll edit that into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ggorlen's comment about the runnable snippet working, I tried this in Chrome and it worked. That led me down a new Googling path where I found this SO question from a while back stating that this exact problem could be [solved by putting `width` and `height` attributes on the root `<svg>` element.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690643/firefox-error-rendering-an-svg-image-to-html5-canvas-with-drawimage)

And, in fact, it did solve the problem!