# Saving inline svg as a image file

Tags: html, svg, onclick, png, inline

I have a inline SVG code that changes base on user selection of colors/css.

I would like to have the ability to save the line svg as a external file  onclick (svg or png or jpeg).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WebbySmart/fof8jqxx/

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<br>
<button>Save Image</button>
```

Is there any way to do this? Much appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Browser content cannot write to a local filesystem, you'd need to send the markup to a server and have the server send it back as a download.

Comment: How would i do that? I am using php.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save inline SVG as JPEG/PNG/SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226677/save-inline-svg-as-jpeg-png-svg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution that works perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/LznLjxq7/

```
<button>svg to png</button>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="200" height="200">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" />
  <text x="0" y="100">Look, i'm cool</text>
</svg>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Stright javascript

```
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

function triggerDownload (imgURI) {
  var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: false,
    cancelable: true
  });

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('download', 'MY_COOL_IMAGE.png');
  a.setAttribute('href', imgURI);
  a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

  a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

  var img = new Image();
  var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

  img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

    var imgURI = canvas
        .toDataURL('image/png')
        .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');

    triggerDownload(imgURI);
  };

  img.src = url;
});
```

Reference from: 
[Save inline SVG as JPEG/PNG/SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226677/save-inline-svg-as-jpeg-png-svg/28226736?noredirect=1#comment50714999_28226736).