# Export SVG as PNG using d3js-wordcloud Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I would like to implement a simple download/export function that will convert and save a rendered svg word cloud as a png in my Angular app.

I am making use of d3 word cloud generator done by Jason Davies and a simplified script by Julien Renaux.

I am trying to add a simple export feature, using iweczek's [*save-svg-as-an-image* export function](http://techslides.com/save-svg-as-an-image), but somewhere I am missing something.

This is my Angular  WordCloud Directive, including the export function at the bottom (`scope.exportToPNG`):

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc: function
 * @name: portalDashboardApp.directive:ogWordCloud
 * @description: Word Cloud Generator based on the d3 word cloud generator done by Jason Davies and a simplified script by Julien Renaux
 * Directive of the portalDashboardApp
 */

angular.module('portalDashboardApp')
  .directive('ogWordCloud', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          templateUrl: './socialMedia.module/socialMedia.templates/WordCloudTemplate.html',
          scope: {
              words: '='
          },
          link: function (scope) {

              var fill = d3.scale.category20b();

              var w = window.innerWidth - 238,
                h = 400;

              var max,
                fontSize;

              var layout = d3.layout.cloud()
                .timeInterval(Infinity)
                .size([w, h])
                .fontSize(function (d) {
                    return fontSize(+d.value);
                })
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.key;
                })
                .on("end", draw);

              var svg = d3.select("#wordCloudVisualisation").append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)
                .attr("xmlns", 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
                .attr("xmlns:xlink", 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')
                .attr("version", '1.1')
                .attr("id", "wordCloudSVG");

              var wordCloudVisualisation = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + [w >> 1, h >> 1] + ")");

              update();

              window.onresize = function (event) {
                  update();
              };

              var tags = [];

              scope.$watch('words', function () {
                  tags = scope.words;
              }, true);

              function draw(data, bounds) {
                  var w = window.innerWidth - 238,
                    h = 400;

                  svg.attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

                  var scale = bounds ? Math.min(
                    w / Math.abs(bounds[1].x - w / 2),
                    w / Math.abs(bounds[0].x - w / 2),
                    h / Math.abs(bounds[1].y - h / 2),
                    h / Math.abs(bounds[0].y - h / 2)) / 2 : 1;

                  var text = wordCloudVisualisation.selectAll("text")
                    .data(data, function (d) {
                        return d.text.toLowerCase();
                    });
                  text.transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                    })
                    .style("font-size", function (d) {
                        return d.size + "px";
                    });
                  text.enter().append("text")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                    })
                    .style("font-size", function (d) {
                        return d.size + "px";
                    })
                    .style("opacity", 1e-6)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .style("opacity", 1);
                  text.style("font-family", function (d) {
                      return d.font;
                  })
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                        return fill(d.text.toLowerCase());
                    })
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.text;
                    });

                  wordCloudVisualisation.transition().attr("transform", "translate(" + [w >> 1, h >> 1] + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
              }

              function update() {
                  layout.font('impact').spiral('archimedean');
                  fontSize = d3.scale['sqrt']().range([10, 100]);
                  if (scope.words.length) {
                      fontSize.domain([+scope.words[scope.words.length - 1].value || 1, +scope.words[0].value]);
                  }
                  layout.stop().words(scope.words).start();
              }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

              scope.exportToPNG = function () {

                  var html = d3.select("svg") //svg
                        .attr("version", 1.1)
                        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
                        .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

                  var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(html);
                  var img = '<img src="' + imgsrc + '">';
                  d3.select("#svgdataurl").html(img);


                  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
                      context = canvas.getContext("2d");

                  var image = new Image;
                  image.src = imgsrc;
                  image.onload = function () {
                      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

                      var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                      var pngimg = '<img src="' + canvasdata + '">';
                      d3.select("#pngdataurl").html(pngimg);

                      var a = document.createElement("a");
                      a.download = "sample.png";
                      a.href = canvasdata;
                      a.click();
                  };
              }
          }
      };
  });
```

**This is my directive template:**

```
<div id="wordCloud">
    <button class="basicButton" ng-click="exportToPNG()">Export to .PNG</button>
    <div id="wordCloudVisualisation"></div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <h2>svgdataurl</h2>
    <div id="svgdataurl"></div>
    <h2>pngdataurl</h2>
    <div id="pngdataurl"></div>
</div>
```

As is, the code generates an broken image (like when an image is missing from a placeholder on a website) in Chrome. In IE it creates an image in my "svgdataurl" but bombs out. I believe it is not compatible with IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix solve my issues, thanks to the following posts:

[Save inline SVG as JPEG/PNG/SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226677/save-inline-svg-as-jpeg-png-svg)

https://gist.github.com/gustavohenke/9073132

**Here is my complete working solution:**

**My Angular directive:**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc: function
 * @name: portalDashboardApp.directive:ogWordCloud
 * @description: Word Cloud Generator based on the d3 word cloud generator done by Jason Davies and a simplified script by Julien Renaux
 * Directive of the portalDashboardApp
 */

angular.module('portalDashboardApp')
  .directive('ogWordCloud', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          templateUrl: './socialMedia.module/socialMedia.templates/WordCloudTemplate.html',
          scope: {
              words: '='
          },
          link: function (scope) {

              var fill = d3.scale.category20b();

              var w = window.innerWidth - 238,
                h = 400;

              var max,
                fontSize;

              var layout = d3.layout.cloud()
                .timeInterval(Infinity)
                .size([w, h])
                .fontSize(function (d) {
                    return fontSize(+d.value);
                })
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.key;
                })
                .on("end", draw);

              var svg = d3.select("#wordCloudVisualisation").append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)
                .attr("xmlns", 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
                .attr("xmlns:xlink", 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')
                .attr("version", '1.1')
                .attr("id", "wordCloudSVG");

              var wordCloudVisualisation = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + [w >> 1, h >> 1] + ")");

              update();

              window.onresize = function (event) {
                  update();
              };

              var tags = [];

              scope.$watch('words', function () {
                  tags = scope.words;
              }, true);

              function draw(data, bounds) {
                  var w = window.innerWidth - 238,
                    h = 400;

                  svg.attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

                  var scale = bounds ? Math.min(
                    w / Math.abs(bounds[1].x - w / 2),
                    w / Math.abs(bounds[0].x - w / 2),
                    h / Math.abs(bounds[1].y - h / 2),
                    h / Math.abs(bounds[0].y - h / 2)) / 2 : 1;

                  var text = wordCloudVisualisation.selectAll("text")
                    .data(data, function (d) {
                        return d.text.toLowerCase();
                    });
                  text.transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                    })
                    .style("font-size", function (d) {
                        return d.size + "px";
                    });
                  text.enter().append("text")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                    })
                    .style("font-size", function (d) {
                        return d.size + "px";
                    })
                    .style("opacity", 1e-6)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .style("opacity", 1);
                  text.style("font-family", function (d) {
                      return d.font;
                  })
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                        return fill(d.text.toLowerCase());
                    })
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.text;
                    });

                  wordCloudVisualisation.transition().attr("transform", "translate(" + [w >> 1, h >> 1] + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
              }

              function update() {
                  layout.font('impact').spiral('archimedean');
                  fontSize = d3.scale['sqrt']().range([10, 100]);
                  if (scope.words.length) {
                      fontSize.domain([+scope.words[scope.words.length - 1].value || 1, +scope.words[0].value]);
                  }
                  layout.stop().words(scope.words).start();
              }

              scope.exportToPNG2 = function () {

                  var svg = document.querySelector('#wordCloudSVG'); //svg
                  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

                  var svgSize = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
                  canvas.width = svgSize.width;
                  canvas.height = svgSize.height;

                  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                  var data = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);

                  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

                  var img = new Image();
                  var svgBlob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' });
                  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

                  img.onload = function () {
                      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                      DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

                      var imgURI = canvas
                          .toDataURL('image/png')
                          .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');

                      triggerDownload(imgURI);
                  };

                  img.src = url;
              }

              function triggerDownload(imgURI) {
                  var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
                      view: window,
                      bubbles: false,
                      cancelable: true
                  });

                  var a = document.createElement('a');
                  a.setAttribute('download', 'MY_COOL_IMAGE.png');
                  a.setAttribute('href', imgURI);
                  a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

                  a.dispatchEvent(evt);
              }

          }
      };
  });
```

**My directive template:**

```
 <div id="wordCloud">
    <button class="basicButton" ng-click="exportToPNG2()">Export to .PNG</button>
    <div id="wordCloudVisualisation"></div>
    <canvas id="WordCloudCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Do the divs `#svgdataurl` and `#pngdataurl` already exist outside your directive? If not, you should include them in your directive template. In the example you're following, they are already present on the page, not created by the `click` function.

You could also look at a similar tool Mike Bostock just released, which uses `canvas.toBlob()`: https://github.com/mbostock/svjimmy/blob/master/index.js.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I appreciate the help. You will see my directive template is actually part of my directive. I don't have an external template file.  `template: '<div id="wordCloud"><button class="basicButton" ng-click="exportToPNG()">Export to .PNG</button><div id="wordCloudVisualisation"></div><canvas id="canvas"></canvas></div>'` Would you give me aome suggestions on the adding of the missing tags?

Comment: I have created an external template for my directive. Please see updated question.