# Export SVG to PNG truncated canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I want to convert an on-screen SVG and download it as a png file upon pressing a button. I found an article ([Save inline SVG as JPEG/PNG/SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226677/save-inline-svg-as-jpeg-png-svg)) which works except for some weird reason, it truncates the output to 300 x 150 when the SVG I have is 800 x 300.

Can you help me to set the canvas size to the size of my SVG so that it can be exported without truncating?

I insert the original link to the jfiddle I used http://jsfiddle.net/LznLjxq7/ from the original post.

In the HTML section, I replaced the svg with my svg as follows:

```
<svg id="mysvg" width="800" height="300"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <text x="50" y="60" fill="black" 
      font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" 
      font-size="28">Revenue and Expenses</text>
   <line x1="150" y1="80" x2="150" y2="320" 
      style="stroke:rgb(155, 144, 144);stroke-width:5" />

  <script type="application/ecmascript"> 
    <![CDATA[
      var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");

      var chartStart = [152, 84, 152]
      var chartWidth = [100,64,36]
      var chartNames = ["$7,110 Revenue", "$4,539 Expenses","$2,571 Profit"]
      var chartColor = ["#28CE6D","#DF3456","#4DC7EC"]
      var num = chartNames.length;

      while (num-- > 0)
      {
       var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
        rect.setAttribute("x", chartStart[num]);
        rect.setAttribute("y", [num] * 70 + 100);
        rect.setAttribute("width", chartWidth[num]);
        rect.setAttribute("height", "50");
        rect.setAttribute("style", "fill:" + chartColor[num] + ";stroke:black;stroke-width:0;opacity:1");

     var label = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
         label.setAttribute("x", "280");
         label.setAttribute("y", [num] *70 + 130);
         label.setAttribute("style", "fill:black");
         label.setAttribute("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif");
         label.setAttribute("font-size","18");
     var txt = document.createTextNode(chartNames[num]);
         label.appendChild(txt);

         mysvg.appendChild(rect);
         mysvg.appendChild(label);
       } 
  ]]>
   </script>
 </svg>
```

The image I get is:

[image: result from jfiddle svg to png]

The image I expected is:

[image: desired result]

UPDATE

I tried out Sydney's suggestion in the comment of adding

```
<svg id="mysvg" viewbox="0 0 800 300"
```

and in the Javascript changing line to an amended version of Sydney's one after reading Mozilla article to this:

```
ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
```

But this has resulted in the full image instead of truncating but at 300 x 150 dimensions which has scaled it to a very low quality image.

How do I make the output be 800 x 300 rather than only having control over the size of an input to be used to create the image? Thanks

Comment: I tried `canvas.setHeight(300);   canvas.setWidth(800);` after declaring var but that didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to just be a matter of setting the canvas width and height properly.  I tried your setHeight() and setWidth() methods and they didn't work for me, but inline width and height solved the problem, without any other additions!

```
<svg id="mysvg" width="800" height="300"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<!-- stuff -->
</svg>
<canvas width="800" height="300" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you for looking at this - that produces a full image but the dimensions it produces is 300 x 150 from a source of 800 x 300. What it produced before was sourcing from `0,0,300,150` and truncating. I think there must be something where we can set the output at the size of the svg which is 800 x 300. Thanks

Comment: I tried the `ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);` from mozilla article and I get same result. I'll try the other