# Using toDataUrl on a canvas result in SecurityError in IE

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Hi I am in need of converting an svg generated by d3.js into a png.This is requried because we are sending our page html to the server that is then passed to ABCPDF and then convert to a pdf file.

We absolutely must support IE9+ the latest version of chrome and latest version of firefox.This is what I have so far:

```
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.setAttribute("width", 360);
    canvas.setAttribute("height", 460);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
    var img = new Image();
    var svg = new Blob([svgString], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        $('#main-chart').append('<img src="' + png + '"/>');
        $('#main-chart svg').remove("svg");
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
    };
    img.src = url;
```

Now this solution works very well on chrome and firefox but for IE it does not work.

When canvas.toDataURL("image/png") gets called a Security error gets thrown.

From what I managed to find online is that this happens because IE does not support CORS when calling toDataUrl().

Has anyone managed to find a work around to this issue?

I have seen other similar questions asked at stackoverflow but could not find one with a solution.

Comment: have you tried [canvg](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg)? + I think that pdf does support vectorial graphics, I remember that with processing I was able to parse an svg to a pdf. Maybe there is something similar with js or server side.

Comment: apparently even ABCPDF does support svg (http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/3-concepts/h-svgsupport.htm), limitations being scripts, animations and opacity in gradients stop-colors

Comment: We are limited to use MSHTML engine and svg is supported only in Gecko Engine in ABCPDF

Comment: huh, while reading, I understood they had their own `native SVG import functionality.` from [this page](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/?page=source%2F3-concepts%2Fh-svgsupport.htm) `The Gecko engine is a component independent of other parts of the Operating System. It will not be affected even if you upgrade your Internet Explorer or another local Firefox installation.`

Comment: Its not releated to firefox instalation its related to how you configure ABCPDF you can configure it to use MSHTML or Gecko we need it to use MSHTML because of some specific features

Comment: ok then, I'll post the way I do rasterization, but I don't have IE9 to test it out.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/q/20322745/3702797

Answer (score 0):

Even [canvg.js](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg) is not able to do the rasterization of DOM elements in IE9.
However, it is able to do it from an url, so one solution could be to save the svg in a temporary file onto the server, and then rasterize it back with canvg.
IMHO, a server side solution such as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4809562/3702797) would be better.

Comment: you solution works fine in chrome but if you open any IE it will not call the onload method for some reason

Comment: what if you try with `addEventListener` ? As I said, I can't test for IE sorry. Maybe img needs to be appended to the page, could you try it too?

Comment: I managed to force a call on it using $(img).load() but now it seems to crash on drawImage with an Unspecified error

Comment: I was able to find the problem with the onload event (ie needs `charset=` ) but still, it does throw a security error…